# Populate SUM of column from accessdb into textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-access, textbox, sum, where-clause

I have a webpage with a few textboxes; and an access database with columns that contain numeric data, dates and user id's.

I need help to SUM a column WHERE the date is >= 1/1/2013.
Lets just say i cant use server side scripting with my current setup. I need this done only by JS or jquery.

Here is the code i came up with to retrieve the sum. but the textbox is returned with this value "[object]".

Also, im not sure how to write the "WHERE" condition.

I'm sure its something simple im missing. any help will be greatly appreciated!!

```
function retrieve_records() {
var adoconn = new ActiveXobject("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS = new ActiveXobject("ADODB.Recordset");
adoconn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='database.mdb'");
adoRS.Open("Select SUM(database_column_name) As Total FROM tablename", adoconn, 1, 3);
textbox1.value = adoRS;
adoRS.close();
adoconn.close();
}
```

Thanks!
Marvin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cobbled to gether from a knowledge of ADO and Access rather than Javascript.

```
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.ActiveConnection = adoconn;

var strSQL = "Select SUM(database_column_name) As Total FROM tablename WHERE aDate=?";

cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
var param = cmd.CreateParameter("adate", 7, 1,, "2013/12/31");
cmd.Parameters.Append(param);
var adoRS = cmd.Execute();
textbox1.value = adoRS.Fields(0)
```

Fields(0) because you only have one field, Fields('Total') should also work. The date is a string above, it should work with Access, but you might like to use a proper date.

Comment: Remou - Thank you for the quick revert. I tried your coded but was getting a "Type Mismatch" error. This is when the DB field properties dont match correct?

so i was trying to debug to get it working without the WHERE condition (appeared that was causing the error. However didnt have luck without the condition either :( 

here is the code i tried:

Comment: `var adoconn = new ActiveXobject("ADODB.Connection");`

`adoconn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='database.mdb'");`

`var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");`

`cmd.ActiveConnection = adoconn;`

`var adoRS = new ActiveXobject("ADODB.Recordset");`

`var strSQL = "Select SUM(database_column_name) As Total FROM tablename";`

`cmd.CommandText = strSQL;`

`var adoRS = cmd.Execute();`

`textbox1.value = adoRS.Fields(0);`

Comment: My database for example has one column with dates and another with numeric value.
--
With the above code, i receive a number "429". And this is not the SUM. I tried modifying the numeric values in my DB and the result remains at 429!! I'm quite puzzled now :(
Tried summing a different column and i get "1013". And this columns sum is only 63! :(
---
guess once we get the basic sum to work, i can venture into adding a condition.
--
looking forward to your help Remou.
Thank you for reading this far and your code.

Comment: I am nearly inclined to delete my answer. Can you try with a numeric parameter? I suspect that the date need a date input type and dates are a pain. `var param = cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 3, 1,, 105);`  and  `WHERE TheNumberColumName=?"` -- 3 is adInteger and 105 is a number that occurs in your table. I hope all this is an exercise and not real life.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, still receiving a sum results not even close to what i have in my database column. :(

Comment: Also, not sure why you mentioned you were inclined to delete your answer?? :(
This is a real life case that I have been struggling with almost a week now. Please dont give up on me yet :(
I tried accessdb.org before i came here. Cannot make head or tail of that.. i'm a novice at this.
any other ideas?
do you need me to post a copy of my database/html file?

Comment: must we try the Groupby clause? I read somewhere that its needed when using SUM. Although clueless how to write this either!

Comment: No, what I wrote runs in MS Access. You only need `Group By` if you have more than one field `.. ID, Sum(This) .. GROUP BY ID`. I am inclined to delete my answer because you might get a different answer if I did. Can you run a query that works in MS Access, that is, use Access to build the query? Can you substitute a value in your WHERE statement? Say `Select SUM(database_column_name) As Total FROM tablename WHERE aDate=#2013/12/31#` and I do mean year/month/day surrounded by hash (#).

Comment: ok. I tried running the query in access and it works like a charm! 
ran this and it returned the correct sum
`Select SUM(database_column_name) As Total FROM tablename WHERE aDate=#2013/12/31#`
tried the same from the web page, doesnt work :(

Comment: the webpage returns **null** in my textbox